# MX Select Plus, multi-select style

Tags: mx-select-plus

I just installed this module hoping to have the nice multi-select interface, but not so!  I'm seeing a javascript conflict in the console.  See screenshot attached.  Any thoughts to resolve?

[image: Generic Multi-select appearance]

[image: console]

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this one out.  Our install uses [Focus Labs global config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config), which rearranges the modules / themes folder structure.  Initially, we had the module & theme directory in this location.  After moving to the default EE location, the module worked as expected.